# Is Captcha good solution for android authentication?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, security, authentication

I'm developing an application (as a part of team) for android that interacts with server (asp.net web service) for synchronize and update information in client side.

for preventing attack to server we use SSL connection and also authenticate users with soap header message contains username and password.

here is the scenario for synchronization:

1. users send web service request with header contains : username , password , time of request , and(for preventing man on the middle attack) hash code of all three parameters(username+password+time) as message signature
2. web service check that :

   - is this a new message by checking the signature of message stored in server
   - if this is a new message (and its not duplicated) then check that signature  is true by hashing all three parameters(username+password+time)
   - then check expiration time : is the message new ( in 5 minute ) for expiring old messages
   - Authenticate username and password
   - validate datatype and length of parameters ( in this case only time of device's last sync )
   - response to request

device get the response as xml file

the question :

because of this scenario we have to give user's devices authentication information so they could interact with server in future and also we don't want to get any information like username and password from users ( for user experience purpose! )

so we build a Web Handler Captcha in server and when users are new, we send them a captcha image generated by their device code(it is uid generated by device something like : https://www.server.com?appid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ) and when if user sends the correct captcha to server we add a new user to our database ( auto username and random password ) and save to the android's account manager for future use

in your opinion  is this a good approach for authentication and security?
Thank you for tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Https  and a method to get a sessionId is enough security for most apps, anyhow my opinion:

Unless you include a secret within the hashed variables a "man in the middle" can change the parameters and forge a valid hash.

I would recomend a registration method. It's going to take device information as parameter, and the captcha if you will.

It's going to return a deviceId and a deviceSecret. The deviceSecret must not be transmitted again, just used as part of the hashes.

Also consider using a counter instead of time. It can help against replay attacks and it's easier overall.

Comment: Thank you for answer . Can "man in the middle" change the parameters even on ssl connection?